# Need a public class in unity but forced to add static

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, public

I want to make a variable editable in the unity inspector by scripting it as a public var - for example, 
`public int days = 3` - 
and then having another private variable that uses `days` (and turns a user-friendly input into a number that is now useful to my code) such as 
`private int hours = days * 24`. However I am forced to make `days` a `public static int` for it to be accessible by the `hours` equation. This means that it is no longer available to change in the inspector. This is, I think, a fundamental problem with my understanding of c#, and any tips for what I should instead be doing would really help a beginner out.

```
public int days = 3;
private int hours = days * 24;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably coz you are setting the hours in the declaration. Move the equation to start method, that should do the trick.

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been much more better if you provided a complete script example. 
By reading your question carefully, this is what you are currently doing:

```
public int days = 3;
private int hours = days * 24;
```

Initialize the `hours` variable in a function and that should be fine. The `Start` or `Awake` function are usually used for something like this:

```
public int days = 3;
private int hours;

void Start()
{
    hours = days * 24;
}
```

*This is because to initialize a variable with another variable, the one you are using to initialize the other one must be a `static` or `const` variable.*

This example with `const` would have worked too:

```
public const int days = 3;
public int hours = days * 24;
```

Comment: good point, i've edited the question, thanks. Okay so I initialise it later. simple. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the key here is C# needs to know when to actually run your `days * 24` line. Let's say you start up your game and then you open up the inspector and change the value of `days` - you'd probably want hours to change to reflect that too.

The easiest way to do this is to run it when you need it - i.e. when you require a value for 'Hours', that's when you'd run `days * 24`. This is best done with a C# Property:

```
public int Days = 3;

public int Hours{
    get {
        return Days * 24;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Hours` as you would use a field, and it'll always be the correct number of hours regardless of when you change that 'Days' field as it'll compute it on demand for you.

Comment: ah so do a small function almost. thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Yep exactly - properties are a special type of small function(s) (you can add a `set` too if you'd like to set `Hours` and have it update `Days` for example). If you've played with any Java before then they're essentially just a pretty way of writing Java getters/ setters. No problem at all - I wish you all the best with your projects! :)

Comment: Quick example of how a `set` might look: `set { Days = value / 24; }` - this lets you do e.g. `Hours = 48;` and `Days` would then be set to 2 for you.